# ASP.NET - new user control added to control collection get unexpectedly a value

Tags: asp.net

I have created user control container (panel actually) which dynamically adding and removing user controls items (like rows). Here is the problem: when the new user control is added to control collection get unexpectedly a value from the previous added control - only on the first post-back.

Detail description:

1. In the initial response I fill one user control item.
2. Then I click on the "Add" button, which adds new user control item to the panel, and this NEW control gets values from previous one (to be more even more confusing new control do not get all values, only form the disabled textBox control and dropDownLists). Why? The UC gets value on the server, when is added in the panel controls collection.

So my implementation with this problem was:

```
            UcSomeControlItem uci = LoadControl("UcSomeControlItem .ascx") as UcSomeControlItem;
            uci.DataSource = new SomeObject;
            uci.DataBind();
            uci.ID = IdPrefix + ControlID;
            ph1.Controls.Add(uci);//At the end
```

When I changed the adding to the panel control collection sequence problem dissapear, sience the UC gets value on the panel adding ...

Like:

```
            UcSomeControlItem uci = LoadControl("UcSomeControlItem .ascx") as UcSomeControlItem;
            ph1.Controls.Add(uci);//Firstly adding ..
            uci.DataSource = new SomeObject;
            uci.DataBind();
            uci.ID = IdPrefix + ControlID;
```

So I would like to know exactly what is going on? Who sets the value to the newly added created control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you add a control to it's container when the container is already on the page, all the lifecycle events (Init, LoadViewState, Load, etc...) are fired sequentially for the newly added control, until it catches up to where the lifecycle of the parent control is currently at.

Because you set the ID of the control and *then* add it to the page, it has the same ID as some previous control when all the catch-up events are fired.  So when LoadPostbackData is fired for the control (which occurs right after ViewState is loaded), ASP.Net assumes it's the same control as before simply because the ID's match, and proceeds to load the previous values into the controls.

When you change it so that you assign the ID *after* you added the control to the page, all the lifecycle events are fired when the control just has an auto-generated ID, so the postback processor doesn't recognize it as a control that existed previously.

Hope that's clear.

Comment: You can have completely different IDs and still run into this issue.  With ViewState, by default, order *is* important.  You have to be sure to preserve the order when adding in dynamic controls, OR, you have to set the [ViewStateModeById] attribute on the container (you'll have to define your own class to do so). 

By using that attribute, ViewState storage (for direct child controls) will be keyed off of the control's ID, and not the control's index, and things will work as you would want.

Comment: That is correct.  I'm actually talking about LoadPostBackData, but most people are totally unaware of the difference.  I updated my answer to be clearer.

Comment: Michael Morton: Yes, my mistake was that I was preserving the IDes. I was not aware of order importance. I am clearing the panel the first time and now works fine. Thanks!